# Python loop until request response code is 200

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to make a python request and proceed with the script when the response status code is 200. Else, keep looping through until I get 200.

Tried the following statements not sure what I am missing here. The condition does not exit the loop.

**Try 1:**

```
while True:
    if (offense_response.status_code == 404):
        time.sleep(5)
        logging.info("Status code is 404, entering sleep for 5 seconds")
        offense_response = requests.get(qradar_offense_url, headers=q_headers, verify=False)
        continue
    if (offense_response.status_code == 200):
        logging.info("Status code is 200, exiting loop")
        exit()
```

**Try 2:**

```
while (offense_response.status_code != 200):
    if (offense_response.status_code == 404):
        logging.info("Status code is 404, entering sleep for 5 seconds")
        time.sleep(5)
        offense_response = requests.get(qradar_offense_url, headers=q_headers, verify=False)
    else: 
        logging.info("Status code is 200, exiting loop")
```

**Try 3:**

```
while True:
    if (offense_response.status_code != 200):
        time.sleep(5)
        logging.info("Checking Response Status Code again")
        offense_response = requests.get(qradar_offense_url, headers=q_headers, verify=False)
        if (offense_response.status_code == 200):
            break
```

Comment: I don't see a new request made. Do you need to retry the call and save the new value to `offense_response`?

Comment: @karthik where in these snippets are you updating/recalculating the offense_response.status_code after waking from sleep ?

Comment: Missed that point, added the retry calls. Still no luck.

Comment: why do you use parethesis in `if` with a single comparison?

Comment: If you get a 404 and then keep trying the same URL, chances are you'll keep getting a 404 and never finish the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this one:

```
status = True
while status:
    if (offense_response.status_code != 200):
        #check the the status and assign to offense_response.status_code
        logging.info("Status code is not 200, entering sleep for 5 seconds")
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        logging.info("status code is 200, hence exiting")
        status = False
```